# CSS3 3D Transform Cube render issue at Firefox

Tags: css, transform

I want to create a 3d cube slider.
It is near ready: http://grtest.hu/cube/
At Chrome the rotate animation is good, but at Firefox there is a space between the slides when rotating:

[image: rotate issue]

Is there a way to fix the animation in Firefox?

Comment: I’m not seeing that in Firefox Aurora (currently v21) on a Macbook Air (Intel graphics). Could it be a driver issue? What happens if you upgrade your Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome both use different toolkit for rendering CSS3. Use -moz- and try it too. Chrome and Safari uses -webkit- and Opera uses -o-
I dunno if I'm making any sense! Lemme know if you meant something else :)

Comment: I already use it:
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -382px ) rotateY( -90deg );
  -moz-transform: translateZ( -382px ) rotateY( -90deg );
  -o-transform: translateZ( -382px ) rotateY( -90deg );
  transform: translateZ( -382px ) rotateY( -90deg );